# How to pass IBus to masstransit consumer constructor

Tags: c#, masstransit, consumer

Good day

I'm registering masstransit consumer this way:

```
var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(RabbitMqOptions.StatusChangeQueueName, e =>
{
e.Consumer(() => new ConsumerProcessingStatusChange(provider));
});
```

and want my consumer to Publish to another exchange
is there a way to get IBus from service provider in consumer constructor?
or should I pass other parameter (which one?)

```
public class ConsumerProcessingStatusChange : IConsumer<***>
    {
        private readonly IBus _bus;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public ConsumerProcessingStatusChange(IServiceProvider provider)
        {
            _bus = provider.GetService<IBus>();
            _mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<MappingProfile>()).CreateMapper();
        }

        public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<***> context)
        {
            await _bus.Publish(_mapper.Map<***>(context.Message));
        }
```

and is it correct way to create mapper here or it could be passed as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to inject `IBus`, and it's not the recommended approach for chaining messages. You should use `context.Publish` instead, which not only will publish your message, but also establish a link between those messages with a proper causation and conversation ids.

In addition, injecting the service provider is a *service locator* antipattern. I could suggest reading at least the [DI docs from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to understand how it should be done.

If you configure your application following the [documentation](http://masstransit-project.com/usage/configuration.html#asp-net-core), you will get your dependencies injected when the consumer is instantiated. In particular, this example shows how it's done:

```
 services.AddMassTransit(x =>
 {
     x.AddConsumer<EventConsumer>();
     x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
     {
         cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("event-listener", e =>
         {
             e.ConfigureConsumer<EventConsumer>(context);
         });
     });
 });
```

When configured like this, the `EventConsumer` instance will get all its dependencies properly injected, if it has any, and these dependencies are properly registered in the services collection.

**But still**, to publish a message from inside the consumer, you better use `context.Publish`.